# String find, replace, and append algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, string, replace, find, append

I need to use `getline(infile, aSentence)` on 4 different sentences in a file and store them as strings. Then, I have to create an algorithm to move the first letter of every word to the last letter, then append "ay" the the word.

For example: "you may call me claptrap" will become "ouyay aymay allcay emay laptrapcay"

What's the best way to do this? I was thinking about using `aSentence.find(" ")` for the white space and `aSentence.append` to add "ay". I have no idea how to move the letter position though.

Hopefully this makes sense, thanks.

Code I have so far (incomplete, but it's the concept):

```
int characterIndex = 0;
char firstChar = sentence.at(characterIndex);
char currentChar = sentence.at(characterIndex);
while (currentChar != '.');
{
    if(currentChar == ' ')
    {
        sentence.replace(characterIndex, "ay")
    }
}
```

Comment: In what language? Or are you looking for pseudocode?

Comment: if you have tried some code, put it in the question, it would be easier to get help!

Comment: Sorry, in c++. Here's what I have so far, partial pseudocode but it's the concept.

Comment: The words are separated only by spaces ?

Comment: Why do you search for `'.'` if your sentence does not have it? Post an example of input file

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to write your function prototype

```
  std::string toPigLatin(const std::string &english);
```

Now write a unit test for it. Pass in Hello world! and get back elloHay orlday! or whatevery you should get.

Now get it it through the unit test. If you pass an index variable i through the english, and append to the pig Latin, then i can be in three states, off-word (in whitespace or punctuation), on word, or on initial letter. We can have 1 letter words so we can go from on initial letter to off-word, but not from off-word to on-word, we have to go through the initial letter state.
When you enter the initial letter state, store the letter in a temporary. When you go into the off-word state, write it out and append an "ay". Otherwise write out the character you just read. Initial state is off-word.